# How can I assign values to a function pointers members in a structure

Tags: c, pointers, function, struct

```
struct a
{
  int (*ptr1)();
  int (*ptr2)();
  int data;
};

typedef struct
{
  struct a x;
}all;

int fun1()
{
  return 5;
};

int fun2()
{
  return 9;
};
```

I can assign like

```
all *mem = (all*)malloc(sizeof(all));

mem->x.ptr1 = fun1;
mem->x.ptr2 = fun2;
```

Is there any other way to assign these function pointers?
Is it possible to assign like this?

```
all *mem;

(void **)mem->ptr1[0] = fun1; 
(void **)mem->ptr2[1] = fun2;
```

Comment: This should work.  What exactly goes wrong?  Do you have an error message?  Which compiler?

Comment: also, why would you do something like this ?

Comment: @Patrick Thanks Patrick, Could you please explain theses statements?

Comment: @Ben I have some old codes, in which they wrote codes like this. But when I try to compile I am getting some errors...

Comment: Sorry, I had the impression that your first example didn't compile.  Your first code is indeed correct.  The second isn't.  Check the answer of jpalecek.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not possible (I assume you actually meant the following, since your code doesn't make much sense)

```
((void **)&mem->ptr1)[0]=fun1;
((void **)&mem->ptr1)[1]=fun1;
```

This is syntactically correct, but quoting the C standard:

> There may be unnamed
>   padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.

which means you are not guaranteed that `((void **)&mem->ptr1)+1 == ((void **)&mem->ptr2)`.

The statement you posted

```
(void **)mem->ptr1[0] = fun1;
```

actually means

```
(void **)((mem->ptr1)[0]) = fun1;
```

which tries to index a function-pointer.

Note that all references like `mem->ptr1` etc. should actually be `mem->x.ptr1` according to your definitions.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't assign like this for many reasons:

1. function pointers are not compatible
   with `void*`. your compiler may
   allow this but this is undefined
   behavior according to the standard
2. By using `[0]` and `[1]` you are doin't pointer arithmetic on
   a `void` pointer, which isn't allowed
   either.

Also in your first example which works, you assign a pointer to a function. This is ok as you did, since a function if you don't put `()` after it evaluates to its address. But still I find it clearer to write `&f` in such case.